# Can't rendering data from function mount() laravel livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have some problem in laravel livewire, when I try to bring up data that i define inside mount() function in the class component which the two relate to each other, but the data doesn't show up on view component

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->allOwners = Owner::all();
    $this->allVehicles = Vehicle::where('owner_id', $this->owner_id)->get();

    $this->allOrders = [
        ['owner_id' => '', 'vehicle_id' => '', 'bbn_kb' => '']
    ];
    $this->resetPage();
}



@foreach($allOrders as $index => $allOrder)
      <x-jet-label for="allOrders[{{ $index }}][owner_id]" value="{{ __('Nama Pemilik') }}"/>
      <select wire:model="allOrders.{{ $index }}.owner_id" name="allOrders[{{ $index}}] owner_id]" id="allOrders[{{ $index }}][owner_id]">
          @foreach ($allOwners as $owner)
             <option value="{{ $owner->id }}">{{ $owner->nama }}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
                            
      <x-jet-label for="allOrders[{{ $index }}][vehicle_id]" value="{{ __('Pilih No. Faktur') }}" />
       <select wire:model="allOrders.{{ $index }}.vehicle_id" name="allOrders[{{$index}}][vehicle_id]" id="allOrders[{{ $index }}][vehicle_id]">
         @foreach ($allVehicles as $vehicle)
             <option value="{{ $vehicle->id }}">{{ $vehicle->no_faktur }}</option>
         @endforeach
       </select>
@endforeach
```